# Survey Web Application

Tags: .net, survey

Are there any (preferably open source, or cost) web controls for survey management that can be used in the .NET environment?

Comment: Not a web control, but you may find useful using a Form from Google Docs (docs.google.com). You can embed it in any web page.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET site has a few options:

http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/browse.aspx?category=44

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a free open source survey product called nsurvey. I see there are still links but I am not 100% sure the project is still running.

http://www.theserverside.net/news/thread.tss?thread_id=33070

Comment: nSurvey was one of the best apps for this back in .net 1.x days.  I would love to see this project revisited.

Answer (score 0):

DotNetNuke comes with it's own range of survey components,including a really basic one out of the box. It's a big install/framework for a one off requirement though.

Answer (score 0):

Try out surveymonkey or ClassApps SelectSurvey (.NET)

http://www.classapps.com/

Answer (score 0):

WebSurvey on Codeplex:
http://websurvey.codeplex.com/